# Session is set or not in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, session

How to check that any of a *Session* is set or not in ASP.NET C# as we do in PHP

```
 if(session_id() == '')
 {
      // session has NOT been started
      session_start();
 }
 else
 {
      // session has been started
 }
```

And in ASP.Net C#

```
if (Session["userRole"].ToString() == "2")
       GridView3.Columns[7].Visible= true;   
else{
       GridView3.Columns[7].Visible= false;
```

The above code only checks the session named *userRole*.
What is the alternate way of the above PHP code to C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check if **any** session key is set try:

```
if(Session.Keys.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Session is filled");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Session is empty");
}
```

Every item is a 'key' in the Session object. So when the count equals zero, there are no session keys set. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

To check if the `session` key exists in `Session` collection you have to compare it with `null`

```
if (Session["userRole"] != null && Session["userRole"].ToString() == "2")
```

**Edit** based on comments, Session is property of Page class and will always exists and will not be null.

> This property provides information about the current request's
>   session. A Session object is maintained for each user that requests a
>   page or document from an ASP.NET application. Variables stored in the
>   Session object are not discarded when the user moves from page to page
>   in the application; instead, these variables persist as long as the
>   user is accessing pages in your application, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Not only for a particular 'userRole', but to check if any of session variable is set....

Comment: Session collection always exists

Comment: @Adil is correct. Session is always there. Checking the keys may determine of there is anything set by the developer

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution use try catch

```
    try
    {
        if (Session["userRole"].ToString() == "2")
            GridView3.Columns[7].Visible = true;
        else
            GridView3.Columns[7].Visible = false;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        GridView3.Columns[7].Visible = false;
    }
```